# Excel - working with text across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel file that uses multiple worksheets to summarize payments and the payment schedule for multiple properties.

It's set up so that the first sheet is a summary of everything, with subsequent sheets detailing different properties. I have a column (just for descriptions) that I want to bring back the text to the first sheet, and if there are multiple entries on subsequent sheets for it to let me know.

I know excel doesn't like working with text across multiple worksheets so this code below worked well to bring out a single entry for me. It will always be in the same cell on subsequent sheets.

```
=IF(COUNTA(Sheet1:Sheet5!D15)=0,"", IF(COUNTA(Sheet1:Sheet5!D15)=1, (Sheet1!D15&Sheet2!D15&Sheet3!D15&Sheet4!D15&Sheet5!D15), "--> Multiple Entries"))
```

However I've come across a situation where I do need to put two identical entries in subsequent sheets.

For an example using | as a sheet break

"" | "Paid #1" | "" | ""

"Paid #1" | "Paid #1" | "" | ""

"" | "Paid #2" | "Paid #1" | ""

Case #2 is the odd one where its ok to have multiple identical entries but #3 where they are different needs to be highlighted, as I have it now (--> Multiple Entries) is enough. Right now both cases would be highlighted.

I don't know where to start really, I can't find a 3d reference (something along the lines of match) that handles text, any suggestions?

As always, thanks in advance, I really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to write a UDF that returns the required string.  Unfortunately UDF parameters don't support 3D ranges, so a work around is required.

Based on your question it apears you want to consider the same cell in all sheets except the summary sheet.  On this basis, this UDF will return a concatenation of the same cell in all sheets except the sheet the formula is placed on.  You can adapt it to return other things as you wish.

Note that I have kept it simple to demo a method, you would need to handle error cases, like r refering to >1 cell, or a cell on another sheet/workbook.

```
Function MergeSheets(r As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As String, s As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Application.Volatile

    a = r.Address
    For Each sh In r.Worksheet.Parent.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> r.Worksheet.Name Then
            s = s & sh.Range(a).Value
        End If
    Next
    MergeSheets = s
 End Function
```